# Binding ng-repeat and ng-model from controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm trying to build a form with ng-repeat and having trouble wrapping my head around the angular stuff.

This is my angular controller:

```
// Create the 'products' controller
angular.module('products').controller('ProductsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',    '$location', 'Authentication', 'Products',
function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Authentication, Products) {
    // Expose the Authentication service
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    $scope.productProperty = {
        productTitle: {slug: 'productTitle', label: 'Product Title', value: '', placeholder: 'Product Title'},
        productCode: {slug: 'productCode', label: 'Product Code', value: '', placeholder: 'Product Code'},
        productModel: {slug: 'productModel', label: 'Product Model', value: '', placeholder: 'Product Model'},
        productColor: {slug: 'productColor', label: 'Product Color', value: '', placeholder: 'Product Color'}
    };

    // Create a new controller method for creating new products
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Use the form fields to create a new product $resource object
        var product = new Products({
            productTitle: this.productTitle,
            productCode: this.productCode,
            productModel: this.productModel,
            productColor: this.productColor
        });

        // Use the product '$save' method to send an appropriate POST request
        product.$save(function(response) {
            // If an product was created successfully, redirect the user to the product's page 
            $location.path('products/' + response._id);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            // Otherwise, present the user with the error message
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
}
]);
```

HTML:

```
    <!-- The create product view -->
<section data-ng-controller="ProductsController">
    <h1>New Product</h1>
    <!-- The new product form -->
    <form data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
        <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="(keyAssets, valueAssets) in productProperty">
            <div>
                <label for="{{productProperty[keyAssets]['slug']}}">{{productProperty[keyAssets]['label']}}</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="productProperty[keyAssets]['slug']" id="{{productProperty[keyAssets]['slug']}}" placeholder="{{productProperty[keyAssets]['placeholder']}}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
        <!-- The error message element -->
        <div data-ng-show="error">
            <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

I'm trying to get the 'data-ng-model' set to something unique in each instance of the data-ng-repeat. But I'm not getting the desired output.

I want something like the following output:

```
<!-- The create product view -->
<section data-ng-controller="ProductsController">
<h1>New Product</h1>
<!-- The new product form -->
<form data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label for="productTitle">Product Title</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="productTitle" id="productTitle" placeholder="Product Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="productCode">Product Code</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="productCode" id="productCode" placeholder="Product Code" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="productModel">Product Model</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="productModel" id="productModel" placeholder="Product Model" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="productColor">Product Color</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="productColor" id="productColor" placeholder="Product Color" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
    <!-- The error message element -->
    <div data-ng-show="error">
        <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I get the 'data-ng-model' set to something unique in each instance of the ng-repeat?

Comment: what is `myCurrentAssets` supposed to be in `ng-repeat`? Shouldn't it be `productProperty ` ?

Comment: It will be `productProperty`. I have edited my post.

Comment: so what is or isn't happening? A demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue would help

Comment: See the demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suhan/9Ymvt/2652/). My problem is the `placeholder` is not set and the `form fields` should be empty but a default value is showing instead. And data-ng-model is not set as like I wanted.

Comment: `ng-model` is 2 way binding. Use another object to bind to

Comment: @charlietfl An example would help me .......

Comment: Demo with streamlined data structure ( array)  http://jsfiddle.net/wcw8h013/

Comment: perhaps you want to bind to `value` ?

Comment: @charlietfl I think you are so close to my desired solution. Please help me with one thing. This is my previous `Products` Constructor in my controller:
`var product = new Products({
                productTitle: this.productTitle,
                productCode: this.productCode,
                productModel: this.productModel,
                productColor: this.productColor
            });`
Please see my controller in my post. Now how can I retrieve the fields value in my `Products` constructor?

Comment: I don't know what `Products()` returns. Put it in demo

Comment: I have edited my last comment. Here Products() is using the form fields to create a new product object. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suhan/wcw8h013/3/)

Comment: but you already have the data object based on my demo in `$scope.dataModel`. Can send that to server and push it into another array containing more products

Comment: @charlietfl I have another problem. I want the data of  `$scope.productProperty` in my controller to load from an external json file. How can I do it?

Comment: same way you load any json in angular , `$http` or `$resource`

Comment: @charlietfl My Server side language is node.js. Consider I have a JSON file name `product.json`. How can I load that file in my controller? An example would be very helpful for me ....